# Concatenating variable into literal string

Tags: lua, string-concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate a variable into a literal string purely for readability purposes e.g.

```
myString = "test"
myString2 = [[
first part of the string
this is a " .. myString .. " string
last part of the string]]
print(myString2)
```

but this literally outputs

```
first part of the string
this is a " .. myString .. " string
last part of the string
```

I'm sure it's something simple but I've tried Googling to find out how to achieve this and came up blank.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The quotes inside the double bracket delimitors aren't doing anything. The only way to end the double bracket is with a double bracket:

```
myString2 = [[
first part of the string
this is a ]] .. myString .. [[ string
last part of the string]]
```

That will give you:

```
first part of the string
this is a test string
last part of the string
```

See: http://www.lua.org/pil/2.4.html

Comment: Exactly. Lua is a programming language based primarily on logic (as is the same with many other programming languages) and therefore all operators such as `(` and `[[` need to be matched with the opposite to that operator (in your case, `]]`).